# SQL Query on multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns

```
ProjectNo | Property | Value
----------+----------+-------
        1 | Manager  | Bob
        1 | Prop1    | foo
        1 | Prop2    | bar
        2 | Manager  | Joe
        2 | Prop1    | Ree
        2 | Prop2    | Mee
```

I want to run a SQL query that returns the `ProjectNo` where `Manager = "Bob" AND Prop1 = "foo" and Prop2 = "bar"`

Result should be 1

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: please First try to write your code And Put result in Your Post

Comment: What's wrong with `Select ProjectNo from table_name where Property in ('Manager', 'Prop1', 'Prop2') and Value in("Bob","foo","bar");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to group by the `projectNo`and take only those having all 3 conditions for each group

```
select projectNo
from your_table
group by projectNo
having sum(case when property = 'Manager' and value = 'Bob' then 1 end) > 0
   and sum(case when property = 'Prop1' and value = 'foo' then 1 end) > 0
   and sum(case when property = 'Prop2' and value = 'bar' then 1 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select ProjectNo from table_name
where (Property = 'Manager' and Value = 'Bob') 
      or (Property = 'Prop1' and Value = 'foo')
      or (Property = 'Prop2' and Value = 'bar')
group by ProjectNo, Property, Value
having count(ProjectNo) = 3
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join pn the table with   condition  for each separated  pair property, value

```
select  m1.projectNo 
from my_table m1 
inner join my_table m2 on m1.projectNo = m2.projectNo
  AND m2.Property = 'Prop1'
    AND  m2.Value = 'foo'
inner join my_table m23on m1.projectNo = m3.projectNo
    AND m2.Property = 'Prop2'
      AND  m2.Value = 'bar'
WHERE m1.Property = 'Manager'
  AND  m1.Value = 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PIVOT`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ec2182b41d129f7c8862f79a9f91476)**

```
SELECT ProjectNo FROM
(SELECT ProjectNo, Property, Value FROM mytbl) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Property IN ([Manager], [Prop1], [Prop2])) AS PivotTable
WHERE  Manager = 'Bob' AND Prop1 = 'foo' AND Prop2 = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to make sure all the 3 properties are there:

```
select ProjectNo
from tablename
where (Property = 'Manager' and Value = 'Bob') 
   or (Property = 'Prop1' and Value = 'foo')
   or (Property = 'Prop2' and Value = 'bar')
group by ProjectNo
having count(distinct Property) = 3
```

Alternatively, use `INTERSECT`:

```
select ProjectNo from tablename where Property = 'Manager' and Value = 'Bob'
INTERSECT
select ProjectNo from tablename where Property = 'Prop1' and Value = 'foo'
INTERSECT
select ProjectNo from tablename where Property = 'Prop2' and Value = 'bar'
```